# Impact of index/unique index on insert

Tags: postgresql, indexing, insert, unique-index

I have a table which will have multimillion insertions, with unique index on column 1 and an index on column 2.How drastic will be the effect on insert statements if i also make the index on column2 a unique index?

Any data or graph which shows the difference will be much helpful

Comment: The indexing overhead will be about twice the indexing overhead with one unique index.  Under most circumstances, the performance win from having the index outweighs the insert overhead.  However, if you are dong hundreds or thousands of inserts per second, then this might be a consideration.

Comment: Performance is nonsense(what is the cost of allowing non-allowable duplicates?) . If it should be unique: make it unique.

Answer (score 0):

There is no notiecable performance difference between a unique and a non-unique B-tree index, but I invite you to run a little benchmark and test that.